# Flask request parameter string limit?

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask

I want to use Python and Flask to serve static html pages which will read arguments from the URL parameters.

I don't know how much data will be passed in with the query strings, and I would like to know what kind of limits there are on Flask's handling of URL parameters? Can I have as many URL parameters as I want, and send as large strings as I want with them?

(The HTML will primarily be requested by a Chrome/Chromium browser)

Comment: Flask has no problems with huge URLs, it is your *browser* you have to worry about here, see the dupe.